# Is there anyway to remove non-alphanumeric elements from a list?

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a huge text document with 100k sentences, and I want to count how many of each letters there are. I was thinking about sending every letter from the string in to a list and then having a function that takes the list and removes all the characters I dont want to count, and then counting them with a dictionary. But I am 1: unsure about if you can even do things like that with a list and 2: if this is the best way to make this program.

```
listy_mc_listface = []
with open("\\Users\\saksa\\python_courses\\1DV501\\assign3\\eng_news_100K-sentences.txt", "r", encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
    string_name=f
    for line in string_name:
        for item in line:
            listy_mc_listface.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use the negative character class in regex to remove symbols.

```
import re
a_count = 0
listy_mc_listface = []
with open("textfile.txt", "r", encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
    string_name=f
    for line in string_name:
        line=re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '', line)
        for item in line:
            listy_mc_listface.append(item)
            if item == 'a':
                a_count = a_count + 1
print(listy_mc_listface)
print(a_count)
```